# Deleting foreign key tables on phpmyadmin? cannot drop index: needed in foreign key constraint

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I've been trying to find a way to delete some foreign keys generated by mistake, but each time I DROP the table associated with the foreign key to try and erase it, it says "cannot drop index: needed in foreign key constraint".

Comment: You don't have to drop a table to drop the indexes. You CAN drop an index by itself. And FYI, "phpmyadmin" is not a database. It's a management interface for mysql.

Comment: thanks, I found the indexes and was able to drop the ones I didn't need. Wasn't a direct, but I saw the light. Thanks Marc.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In "Structure" tab, click on "see relational view" below the fields.
Here you can remove the foreign keys by selecting an empty value in the dropdown.

Comment: Tip: If you don't have "see relational view" try "Relation view"

Comment: If your table uses several foreign keys, I find CFreak's answer dated 2014-09-02 faster: SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; DROP TABLE yourtable;

Comment: thanks for this, really heped with removing some relational keys off an old project I have been working on and couldn't recreate some tables because of relational keys stuck on the older tables I can just remove and add what was needed to update this

Answer (score 10):

You have to delete the foreign key with an alter statement:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable DROP CONSTRAINT yourforeignkeyname
```

You might be able to force drop it as well (works in the MySQL console but might not work in phpmyadmin as I'm not sure how sessions are handled)

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; DROP TABLE yourtable;
```

Note: this is very dangerous and not recommended if you're seriously using foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks! +1, don't forget to reset SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

Answer (score 3):

The best way to drop a table with relation in phpmyadmin, click on "SQL" tab, uncheck  `Enable foreign key checks` and run:
`DROP TABLE yourtablename`.

Comment: Similarly on the "Import" tab. Thank you for pointing this out! My uploaded .sql file was erroring out on the DROP TABLE commands due to foreign key checks.